# What is the local timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Assuming the server (gae) is on the US west coast (PST), an appointment is in New York City (EST) at 10:00am and a person in Chicago (CST) is using his device to know the time of the appointment in NYC.

How can the the person in Chicago's device in CST see that the appointment is at 10am when she goes to the website that resides in EST, and does it matter how the developer, who was in MST, sets up parameters in datetime, time, and calendar using python?

Also, what timezone is "local time" here?

Comment: The west coast of the US is Pacific time (PST), although at the moment very little of the US is using standard time at all, so you want PDT. Also, the GAE servers all use UTC on their clocks, even though the logfiles show pacific time by default.

Comment: Great answer, Wooble. And what is "local time" here? Is it EST, the place where the "client" html is generated?

Comment: Let me think about this before I ask more.

Comment: I **did** use that phrase in my question because the phrase is not clear to me when it is used in docs and conversation. Thanks.

Comment: @zerowords: In the docs "local time" refers to the time the local machine (the one running the process) thinks is the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third-party module, [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), provides an easy way to convert between timezones. For example,

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc
western = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
newyork = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
chicago = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
```

Suppose someone creates an appointment at 10am in New York:

```
date = dt.datetime(2012, 8, 12, 10)    # naive datetime
print(date)
# 2012-08-12 10:00:00  

# localize converts naive datetimes to timezone-aware datetimes.
date_in_newyork = newyork.localize(date)  # timezone-aware datetime
print(date_in_newyork)
# 2012-08-12 10:00:00-04:00
```

Your server on the west coast should store this datetime in UTC:

```
# astimezone converts timezone-aware datetimes to other timezones.
date_in_utc = date_in_newyork.astimezone(utc)
print(date_in_utc)
# 2012-08-12 14:00:00+00:00
```

Now when the person in Chicago wants to know what time the appointment is, the server can convert UTC to Chicago time, or New York time, or whatever:

```
date_in_chicago = date_in_utc.astimezone(chicago)
print(date_in_chicago)
# 2012-08-12 09:00:00-05:00

date_in_newyork2 = date_in_utc.astimezone(newyork)
print(date_in_newyork2)
# 2012-08-12 10:00:00-04:00
```