# installing pytz in gae is giving UnknownTimeZoneError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, timezone, pytz

[unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) answered my previous question nicely [here 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925664/what-is-the-local-timezone), but there does not appear to be a pytz to import directly using my SDK. So I went looking for alternatives and found, for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843148/importerror-using-pytz-in-google-app-engine) which recommends downloading from [here 4](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gaepytz).

I placed the following code in my local interactive console.

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc
western = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
```

I put the downloaded directory `pytz` in my local root directory `scheduler` and I unzipped the included file `scheduler/pytz/zoneinfo.zip` and got the following error in the interactive console. I did NOT adjust `app.yaml` at all; is that correct?

```
"/Users/brian/googleapps/scheduler/pytz/__init__.py", line 173, in timezone
    raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
UnknownTimeZoneError: 'US/Pacific'
```

I also found an answer to a similar error [here 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718724/how-to-properly-add-pytz-to-a-google-app-engine-application) which recommends a patch to the **init**.py file.

Now I have found an answer [here 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718724/how-to-properly-add-pytz-to-a-google-app-engine-application) which suggests that errors occur if VERSION 2010h is used instead of VERSION 2011h and the pytz I downloaded is 2010h. What is UP?

Is there an easy way to be able to use Wooble's answer with pytz. And does his answer imply I have to upload the `pytz` directory with my gae app when it is deployed or is there a pytz alread there?

Comment: Uh, thanks, but I didn't answer that question, I only left a somewhat snarky comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `from pytz.gae import pytz` in order that gae-pytz will work, otherwise you will be using the regular pytz.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks. That fixed the error message. Now I need to know if even though my pytz VERSION is 2010h, does gae have pytz VERSION 2011h? And if gae has the correct version does that mean when I deploy my app I should not include my local pytz directory in the upload? Otherwise, where do I get VERSION 2011h?

Comment: You should use (and upload) the latest zoneinfo as time zone info is updated around the world constantly. you can get the folderinfo.zip from the [pytz site](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/)

Comment: So are you saying that it is only the zoneinfo VERSION that was old, not the pytz (it sure looked to me as if it was the pytz VERSION itself that was old)? And please answer my question about whether I should upload the pytz folder when I deploy, or is that unnecessary?

Comment: gae-pytz did change much in the past couple of years only folderinfo.zip. You should upload the whole package with the zip.